# Looking for an example of a process that holds the Markov property but doesn't hold the strong Markov property

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am desperately looking for a Markov process which does only hold the Markov property but doesn't hold the strong Markov property. All examples I can think of hold the Markov property, as well as the strong Markov property. Could some one maybe give me an example of a process that does hold the Markov property but doesn't hold the strong Markov property?

Comment: See answers at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43833/a-markov-process-which-is-not-a-strong-markov-process

Comment: @Henry Thanks a lot! This was really were I was looking for. If you write an official answer I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three voted-up examples at [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43833/a-markov-process-which-is-not-a-strong-markov-process).  The accepted example from George Lowther said

> Consider the following continuous Markov process $X$, starting from
>   position $x$
>
> 1. if $x = 0$ then $X_t=0$ for all times.
> 2. if $x \not = 0$ then $X$ is a standard Brownian motion starting from $x$.
>
> This is not strong Markov (look at times at which it hits zero).

Comment: How can I show this process has the Markov property? I cannot prove it.

Comment: @IreneGil I suspect the argument is that if $X_t=0$ then with probability $1$ you are in state $1$ and so given $X_t=0$ you have $X_s=0$ with probability $1$ for $s \gt t$.   Meanwhile given  $X_t=k \not = 0$ then $X_s \sim N(k, s-t)$.  Either way the distribution of $X_s$ does not depend on what happened before $t$.  That changes if instead of $t$ you use $\tau$ as a stopping time such as when state $2$ first hits $X_\tau=0$

Comment: Thank you @Henry, but I still do not know how to prove it by proving that for any $B$ a Borel set we have that
$E[\mathbb{1}_{B}(X_{t+s})|\mathcal{F}_{s}]=E[\mathbb{1}_{B}(X_{s})]$